# Connect NAS via 10Gbit additionally to 1GBit connection

Tags: networking, freenas

I think the diagram describes best, what I try to achieve. 
I want to make a direct 10Gbit connection to my FreeNAS Server, additionally to my existing 1Gbit connection.

Will the 10Gbit card on the server get its own IP, that I can connect directly to a share with ? And is there any interference or troubles with this approach ?

[image: Network diagram link]

Comment: Presumably you can hard code an IP addresses for the 10gb network (in a range different to the 1gig one) on both PC and server.

Comment: I've had an exact setup like this once, and as @davidgo suggested, static IP assignments are the way to go. Just throw them on a different subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are running a DHCP server on one of the boxes, your servers won't automatically get IP addresses assigned to their 10gbit interfaces.

You can, however, assign static IP addresses manually perfectly fine! Just throw them on a different subnet than your 1gbit network. On a small network like this, manual assignment is probably a lot easier to do.